# Features for sentiment analysis using Maxent model

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I want to implement my own sentiment analysis using maximum entropy model. without using any Api. what could be the best features f(c,d) for my maximum entropy model. I have three classes positive, negative and neutral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the most used and effective features in Sentiment Analysis are **unigrams**. **Bigrams** can also be employed, but it is quite controversial whether they are really useful or not.

Note that using frequency values of unigrams/bigrams does not significantly improve results in Sentiment Analysis; it is therefore generally sufficient to extract word types and use a boolean value to express their presence/absence in a text.

The important thing is how you preprocess text before you extract these features. For example, apart from lower-casing your tokens, handling negation scopes can improve your results when extracting unigram features.

In any case, Sentiment Analysis is a wide field. You will find that different feature extraction strategies could yield different results depending on the specific type of analysis you need to perform (e.g. feature-based analysis, subjectivity analysis, polarity analysis, etc.).

You can find almost everything you need to get started here:

- http://sentiment.christopherpotts.net
- Liu, Bing. "Sentiment analysis and opinion mining." Synthesis Lectures on Human Language Technologies 5.1 (2012): 1-167.
- Pang, Bo, and Lillian Lee. "Opinion mining and sentiment analysis." Foundations and trends in information retrieval 2.1-2 (2008): 1-135.